# Validate XML element tag

Tags: java

I am having a XML file like

```
<parent>
  <child1>
   <child2>
     <name>name</name>
     <value>
     <item>value></item>
    </value>
  </child2>
 </child1>
  <child1>
   <value>
     <item>value></item>
    </value>
 </child1>
</parent>
```

Here i need to check, whether child2 node is missing or not.

My java code is like

```
File xmlfile = new File ("sample.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfaFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dbfaFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlfile);
NodeList child1= doc.getElementsByTagName("child1");
for( int i=0; i<child1.getLength(); i++)
{
NodeList child1= doc.getElementsByTagName("child1");
if(!doc.getElementsByTagName("child2").equals(null))
{
System.out.println("Not Equal to null");

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Equal to null");
                }
}
```

But every time i am getting Not Equal to null, even though child2 node is missing in the XML.

Here child2 is missing

```
<child1>
   <value>
     <item>value></item>
    </value>
 </child1>
```

Thanks.

Comment: if condition is for child1 and not for child2.

Comment: if(!doc.getElementsByTagName("child1").equals(null)) not sure if this can cause a nullpointer exception (null.equals) cause child1 could be null

Answer (score 1):

This code cannot work: `doc.getElementsByTagName("child2")` traverses the whole XML, i.e. it returns ANY child2 it can find.

Either try using `child1.getElementsByTagName("child2")`, or consider using a "sane" XML library. XOM for example has a function [`getChildElements(String name)`](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/) which works in the way you would expect.

EDIT: As Jenson noted, you might run into `NullPointerException`s with that null check clause, use `child1.getElementsByTagName("child2") != null` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might find XPath is well-suited for this task:

```
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("sample.xml"));

        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("/parent/child1/child2");

        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
        }
```

If `child2` is there, then `nodeList.getLength()` will equal one (or the number of `child2` elements there are under `child1`), otherwise it will be zero.

If you want all the instances where `child1` has a child that is not `child2` you can use:

```
/parent/child1/*[not(self::child2)]
```

as your XPath expression.  If you only want to count the number of times that `child1` has any children that are not `child2` then you can use:

```
/parent/child1/*[not(self::child2)][1]
```

Comment: Your code will never detect that the second `child1` element is missing its `child2` element though, instead it will only print the first `child2` element. Either you would need to write a more complex XPath expression, or you'd need to abandon XPath and stick to using a DOM.

Comment: Edited answer with some options for XPath expressions that would capture different information.